# Symfony 2 - Where should I put a utility class?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm creating a class that will have one public method, which returns a value indexed by a parameter.  I have a single bundle at present.  The directories inside the bundle I currently have are:

```
/Controller
/DataFixtures
/DependencyInjection
/Document
/Entity
/Resources
/Tests
```

What is the convention for placement of a class like this?

Comment: That depends. You normally start with writing a test that fails first. Can you share the code of your test? That's often helpful to locate the right place of a class then.

Comment: @hakre Thanks for the advice.  I would love to start adopting TDD but I'm not there yet.  I'll give it a shot at whipping one up.  Since this is not a controller where do I stick the test? Do I just put it under the Tests directory?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your question is a bit subjective, but according to what is outlined in [Bundle Structure and Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html), a Bundle is just namespaced code. If the utility class is of first-grade, why don't you place it into the root-dir of the Bundle?

```
Namespace Bundle\HelloBundle;

Class Utility {
    public static function returnIndexedValueByParameter($parameter) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Filename:

```
Bundle/HelloBundle/Utility.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I decided to create a directory in the bundle named Utility and stick it there. That idea was suggested by doing a quick read of the http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html doc.  In a related question, I've seen some discussion of using a "Model" directory.  We have some hybrid ORM/MongoDB Models where we plan to persist data in both mysql and a Doctrine collection.  In your opinion, would "Model" be the place to put these hybrid models?

Comment: Ah and please drop thea link to the related question, it's often helpful to cross-link questions.

Comment: sorry on that last point, I'm not following you.. what related question are we talking about?

Comment: You wrote in the comment above: *"In a related question, I've seen some discussion of using a "Model" directory"*. I mean a link to that question.

Comment: Ahh sorry for the confusion -- just a turn of phrase on my part. I meant that i had a related question/follow up to the original one I posed.  Thanks much for your advice here.

Comment: @hakre How I can access the function from another bundle? For example from an entity or a controller

Answer (score 32):

Symfony official website suggest `src/AppBundle/Utils`

Source : http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html

Comment: Thanks for providing this update, now that the documentation includes a recommendation.